# OpenCV convertTo from bmp image to double/CV_64FC1 not giving same values as in Matlab

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV C++, I tried

```
cv::Mat mat=cv::imread("input.bmp");
mat.convertTo(mat, CV_64FC1, 1.0/255.0);
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    std::cout<<"\n";
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        std::cout<<mat.at<double>(i,j)<< " ";
    }   
}
```

The values match what I get in Matlab, but if I try:

```
for (int i=314; i<316; i++) {
    std::cout<<"\n";
    for (int j=350; j<352; j++) {
        std::cout<<mat.at<double>(i,j)<< " ";
    }   
}
```

The values I get are

```
.165 .189 
.274 .208
```

While in Matlab, if I do

```
im=imread("input.bmp")
im2double(im(315:316,351:352))
```

I get

```
.294 .310
.317 .294
```

why is this?

Comment: Try printing the top-left 4 pixels, i.e. the first two columns of the first two rows.

Comment: I modified the post. Printing the top-left 4 pixels match what I get in Matlab, but when I print out some other pixels, the values don't match

Comment: I believe in Matlab - first index is row while second is column. In openCV it should be the opposite, first index is column while second is the row.

Comment: in opencv, first index is row, second is column.